# Extract synonyms and label from Turtle file using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, turtle-rdf

I am in a learning phase of SPARQL. I am working with a Turtle file to extract some information. The condition is: if the exact synonym has a substring 'stroke' or 'Stroke', the query should return all the synonyms and `rdfs:label`.

I am using below query but getting no output:

```
prefix oboInOwl: <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#>
prefix obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
               
Select * where { 
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  rdfs:label <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym> "stroke"^^xsd:string
}
```

Below is the sample Turtle file:

```
###  https://ontology.aaaa.com/aaaa/meddra_10008196

:meddra_10008196 
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref> "DOID:6713" , "EFO:0000712" , "EFO:0003763" , "HE:A10008190" ;
  <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym> 
    "(cva) cerebrovascular accident" , 
    "Acute Cerebrovascular Accident" , 
    "Acute Cerebrovascular Accidents" , 
    "Acute Stroke" , 
    "Acute Strokes" ;
  rdfs:label "Cerebrovascular disorder"@en ;
  :hasSocs "Nervous system disorders [meddra:10029205]" , "Vascular disorders [meddra:10047065]" ;
  :uid "6e46da69b727e4e924c31027cdf47b8a" .
```

I am expecting this output:

```
(cva) cerebrovascular accident
Acute Cerebrovascular Accident
Acute Cerebrovascular Accidents
Acute Stroke
Acute Strokes
Cerebrovascular disorder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this triple pattern, you are querying for `rdfs:label` as subject, not as predicate:

> ```
> rdfs:label <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym> "stroke"^^xsd:string
> ```

What you are asking with this is: "Does the resource `rdfs:label` have the property `oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym` with the string value 'stroke'?"

But you want to ask this about the class (e.g., `:meddra_10008196`), not `rdfs:label`:

```
?class oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym "stroke" .
```

#### Finding matches

As you don’t want to find only exact string matches, you can use [`CONTAINS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains):

```
?class oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym ?matchingSynonym .
FILTER( CONTAINS(?matchingSynonym, "stroke") ) .
```

As you want to ignore case, you can query lower-cased synonyms with [`LCASE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase):

```
?class oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym ?matchingSynonym .
FILTER( CONTAINS(LCASE(?matchingSynonym), "stroke") ) .
```

#### Displaying results

To display the label and all synonyms in the same column, you could use a property path with `|` ([*AlternativePath*](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#pp-language)):

```
?class rdfs:label|oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym ?labelOrSynonym .
```

#### Full query

```
# [prefixes]

SELECT ?class ?labelOrSynonym
WHERE {

  ?class rdfs:label|oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym ?labelOrSynonym .

  FILTER EXISTS {
    ?class oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym ?matchingSynonym .
    FILTER( CONTAINS(LCASE(?matchingSynonym), "stroke") ) .
  }

}
```

Comment: Well explained. I wish I could upvote your answer few more times. Thank you so much!         
Is it possible to extract the terms instead of URI?

Comment: Does the above query provide only the synonym with 'stroke' or other associated synonyms with stroke as well (with NO Stroke mentioned as shown in the expected output)

Comment: @rshar **1)** What do you mean with "terms instead of URI"? The query outputs a URI in the first column (= the URI of the class), and a string in the second column (= a synonym or a label). **2)** The expected output, according to your question, includes *all* synonyms (no matter what they are) and the label, right? So my query does that, too: as soon as a class matches (i.e., it has at least one synonym that contains "stroke"), it displays every synonym of this class + the label.